# How can I have a div sliding down or sliding up by a multiple select boxes selection

Tags: jquery, forms, html, slidedown

So what I want is a code to have a div showing up when a variety of select boxe's value are selected.

**Here is my html / css code:**

```
<body>
Selecção de produtos <br />
<form name="encomendaflyers">
<select name="flp">
    <option value="sf">Só Frente</option>
    <option value="fv">Frente e verso</option>
</select><br /><br />
Formato <br />
<select name="flf">
    <option value="a6">A6</option>
    <option value="a5">A5</option>

</select><br /><br />
Gramagem <br />
<select name="flg">
    <option value="80">80</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select><br /><br />

</form>

<div id="price1" style="display: none;">10€</div>
<div id="price2" style="display: none;">20€</div>
<div id="price3" style="display: none;">30€</div>
<div id="price4" style="display: none;">40€</div>
<div id="price5" style="display: none;">50€</div>
<div id="price6" style="display: none;">60€</div>
```

And here is my jquery code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#encomenda_flyers").change(function(){

        if ($(this).val() == "sf" && $(this).val() == "a6" &&  $(this).val() == "80")   {

            $("#price1").slideDown("slow"); //Slide Down Effect

        } else {

            $("#price1").slideUp("fast");    //Slide Up Effect

        }
});

    });

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#encomenda_flyers").change(function(){

        if ($(this).val() == "fv" && $(this).val() == "a5" &&  $(this).val() == "100")   {

            $("#price1").slideDown("slow"); //Slide Down Effect

        } else {

            $("#price1").slideUp("fast");    //Slide Up Effect

        }
});

    });


</script>
```

What i need is, for instance, when option values sf, a6 and 80 are simultaneously selected to show, div price1 slides down, else if a5, sf and 80 are selected, div price 2, slides down, and so far.

Any help?

Comment: That `if` statement is never gonna return `true` since you are testing against strings and they can't be all equal to a unique thing. You probably mean: `if ($(this).val() == "sf" || $(this).val() == "a6" ||  $(this).val() == "80")`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add in all your own `if` statements, but I've made your code work here: http://jsfiddle.net/FRR9B/

There are two important parts there. The first one is the selector in for the `.change` function. By changing it to `$("form select")` you will be listening for a change on any of the select boxes in the form.

The next important ones are in the if statement. `$(this)` won't really work here since you're looking for values in each of the select boxes. You instead need to use `$('select[name=x]')` replacing x with each select box name.

Comment: @HugoSerraRiço - Happy to help. If an answer is helpful you should up vote it. If an answer solved your question you should accept it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```html
Selecção de produtos <br />
<form name="encomendaflyers">
    <select id="flp" name="flp">
        <option value="sf">Só Frente</option>
        <option value="fv">Frente e verso</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    Formato <br />
    <select id="flf" name="flf">
        <option value="a6">A6</option>
        <option value="a5">A5</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    Gramagem <br />
    <select id="flg" name="flg">
        <option value="80">80</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
</form>
<div id="price1" class="hiddenPrice" style="display: none;">10€</div>
<div id="price2" class="hiddenPrice" style="display: none;">20€</div>
<div id="price3" class="hiddenPrice" style="display: none;">30€</div>
<div id="price4" class="hiddenPrice" style="display: none;">40€</div>
<div id="price5" class="hiddenPrice" style="display: none;">50€</div>
<div id="price6" class="hiddenPrice" style="display: none;">60€</div>
​
```

**Javascript**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flp, #flf, #flg").on('change', function() {

        if ($('#flp').val() === "sf" && $('#flf').val() === "a6" && $('#flg').val() === "80") {
            $('.hiddenPrice').slideUp();
            $("#price1").slideDown("slow"); 
        } else if ($('#flp').val() === "fv" && $('#flf').val() === "a5" && $('#flg').val() === "100") {
            $('.hiddenPrice').slideUp();
            $("#price2").slideDown("slow"); 
        } else {
            $('.hiddenPrice').slideUp();
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KMjmW/1/)**